# Как посчитать количество символов в объекте html input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, валидация

Как при вводе посчитать количество символов в объекте html input и вывести в сообщение с помощью JS?

Пытаюсь это делать так:

```
<script>
    inputTel.addEventListener('keyup', funcCount(evt));

    $("#inputTel").on("input", funcCount2);

    var funcCount2 = function () {
        let length = $("#inputTel").text(this.value.length);
        if (length > 12) msg.textContent = 'Количество символов не должно превышать 12!';
        else if (length < 11) msg.textContent = 'Количество символов не должно быть меньше 11!';
        alert(msg.textContent);
    }

    var funcCount = function (evt) {
        let length = this.value.length;
        if (length > 12) msg.textContent = 'Количество символов не должно превышать 12!';
        else if (length < 11) msg.textContent = 'Количество символов не должно быть меньше 11!';
        alert(msg.textContent);
    }
</script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <form class="form-horizontal" asp-action="Register" asp-controller="Account" asp-anti-forgery="true" method="post">
            <div class="validation" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Telephone">Телефон (в федерал. формате)</label><br />
                <input type="text" id="inputTel" asp-for="Telephone" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Telephone" />
            </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но это не работает.
Подскажите где ошибка/ошибки?

Ошибки:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: evt is not defined
> at Register:93

Comment: `let length = $("#inputTel").text(this.value.length); -> let length = this.value.length;` не оно?

Comment: Добавьте код ошибки в описание вопроса;

Comment: @XelaNimed, ну я так и делаю в своем варианте, но не срабатывает

Comment: @AndrewHolovko, добавил

Comment: в первой же строке вызываете фнкцию с неопределнным аргументом вместо навешивания обработчика

Comment: @teran, подскажите как правильно сделать

Comment: понять в чем разница между обычным вызовом функции, и передачей имени функции в обработчик. выяснить для этих целей что собственно значат скобки после имени функции в коде (не в описании самой функции, а непосредственно в коде)

Comment: @teran, ссылку на материал описывающий конкретно эти моменты можете дать?

Comment: вы не знаете разницу, когда в коде просто пишешь `func` и `func()` ?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir у вас при этом условии (length < 11) каждый "тык" будет alert вываливаться, если oninput или keyup используете. И если JQ используете то длину так получать надо $("#inputTel").val().length; А вообще сделать по кнопке общую валидацию.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#validation-attributes

Comment: @XelaNimed тогда уж сюда https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute?view=net-5.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const inputTel = document.querySelector('#inputTel')
    let msg
    inputTel.addEventListener('focusout', event=>{
        let length = inputTel.value.length
        if (length > 12) msg = 'Количество символов не должно превышать 12!'
        else if (length < 11) msg = 'Количество символов не должно быть меньше 11!'
        alert(msg);
    })
```

Думаю будет лучше использовать событие focusout или клик по кнопке, так как при каждом вводе в поле input будет всплывать alert

Comment: вы уверены, что во встроенных механизмах валидации форм ASP.net  нет заданного функционала и надо городить вот это все?

Comment: есть, но хочется чтобы это выполнялось на фронте, чтобы меньше дергать сервер

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir а вы считаете, что атрибуты применяются только для бекэнда?

Comment: @teran, нет не только, но обрабатываются они на бекэнде, или я не прав?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir вы же не с поделкой студента работаете а с глоабально распространенным фреймворком, естественно там тоже люди озадачивались тем, чтобы валидировать данные предварительно без отправки данных на бэкенд.

Comment: @teran, я только изучаю этот фреймворк, поэтому ещё не все моменты знаю. Теперь буду знать